# javascript to show hidden divs on change of drop down menu when radio button is already set to yes

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, radio-button

Hi I have a dropdown with different selections when i select the second option there is a set of yes/no radio buttons once I select yes I show divs of hidden fields and then when I change the value of the dropdown I hide those fields. The problem is when I come back to the second selection in the dropdown the yes radio button is already selected but the hidden fields are not showing like they did the first time unless I click on the yes radio button. How do I get the hidden fields to show when the radio button is already yes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tea").hide();
  $("#milk").hide();
                $("#coffee").hide();
$("#teano").hide();
                $("#teayes").hide();
$("#testradio").hide();


$('#q1').click(function() {
if ($(this).val() === 'y') {
  $("#testradio").show();
} else if ($(this).val() === 'n') {
  $("#testradio").hide();
} 
});



    $("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                $("#tea").hide();
  $("#milk").show();
   $("#testradio").hide();
                $("#coffee").hide();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
               $("#tea").show();
   $("#testradio").hide();
  $("#milk").hide();
                $("#coffee").hide();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="3"){
                $("#tea").hide();
  $("#milk").hide();
                $("#coffee").show();
  $("#testradio").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
  });
  </script>
   </head>
 <body>
   <div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose beverage</option> 
        <option value="1">milk</option>
        <option value="2">tea</option>
        <option value="3">coffee</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="milk">

 milk choices go here</div>
<div id="tea">
 caffeine
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="q1" id="q1" VALUE="y">Yes
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="q1" id="q1" VALUE="n">No
 </div>
 <div id="teayes">
 tea yes
 </div>

  <div id="testradio">
 test radio button show
</div>

<div id="teano">
 tea no
</div>
<div id="coffee">
coffee goes here</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you show the html as well, please?

Comment: hi ghan I updated my code to include html it also shows the problem I am having when I change the dropdown menu

Answer (score 2):

Fast solution:

```
$('select[name="teas"]').on('change', function (e) {...}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me by a few seconds - pluso uno for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger it

```
$('select[name="teas"]').on('change', function (e) {}).change();
```